# What happens to a MEP who is suspended (or even expelled) from his own party in his home country?

Tags: european-union, european-parliament

There have been some recent cases of British MEPs [being suspended from their party "at home"](http://conservativeeurope.com/news/two-conservative-meps-stripped-of-party-whip/). What are the implications of such moves for their activities (and EU-level groups) as a MEP? Do they lose their membership in the corresponding EU Parliament group, or is any of that subject to subsequent voting that involves more than their national party (group)?

Comment: I suspect MEPs represent their constituents not their parties. Therefore their membership of any party is irrelevant to their qualification for office. Perhaps they get lumped in with independents or can choose their EU parliamentary group. Also suspension is not the same as expulsion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEPs who are suspended from their party would remain MEPs. They may or may not remain part of the group in the European Parliament, but in the cases I have seen they would also leave the group.

Richard Ashcroft, was suspended by the Tory party in Oct 2017. He remained in the ECR group until Feb 2018. He then [left the ECR group and joined the EPP group](http://www.richardashworth.org/?p=802). He was free to do this as he was not subject to Conservative party rules (that require all their members to join the ECR group)

Janice Atkinson was expelled from UKIP. She [left EFDD and joined EFF](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-parliaments-34574041).